# How To Access to Global Confin within Model Class in ZF2

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I want to have access to database config set in global config file within my model. In ZF2 controllers we can load configs using `getServiceLocator` method, but how can i do this in my Model class ? here is my Model class:

```
class BaseModel extends AbstractTableGateway
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->adapter = new Adapter(array(
            'driver' => 'Pdo_Mysql',
            'database' => 'mydbname',
            'username' => 'root',
            'password' => 'root'
        ));
    }
}
```

I just want to load 'db' array config ( located in global config file) and replace with this input array as a Adapter class input parameters.

Here is my global config file:

```
return array(

    "db" => array(
        "driver" => "Pdo_Mysql",
        "dsn" => "mysql:dbname=mydbname;host=localhost",
        "username" => "root",
        "password" => "root"
    ),

    "service_manager" => array(
        "factories" => array(
            "dbFactory" => "Zend\Db\Adapter\AdapterServiceFactory",
        )
    )

);
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to pass in your existing DB adapter, instead of creating a second connection?

Comment: It's exactly what i want to do ... i want to use existing 'db' adapter ( in global.php file ) in my model class as Adapter parameters array. but i can't, how i can load that in my model ?

Comment: with this strategy i dont need to make a function wich return my table model class in each request in controller, instead i inheritance  my table model from base model and jsut make instance from my table model in my controller, just that.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to modify the `DbAdapter` config (the database you are connecting to) you'll need to create a different instance of the adapter and then **inject the adapter** that into your 'model'

```
class FooModel extends AbstractTableGateway
{
    public function __construct($dbAdapter)
    {
        $this->adapter = $adapter;
    }
}
```

Then create the adapter service factories

```
public function getServiceConfig()
{
   return array(
       'factories' => array(

           // Standard database adapter
           'dbAdapter1' => function($sm) {
              $config = $sm->get('config');
              return new \Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter($config['db']);
           }, 
           // Another db adapter using different config
           'dbAdapter2' => function($sm) {
              $config = $sm->get('config');
              return new \Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter($config['db2']);
           }, 

           // The model that requires a different database
           // adapter to be injected
           'FooModel' => function($sm) {
              $adapter = $sm->get('dbAdapter2');
              return new Model\FooModel($adapter);
           }, 

       ),
   );
}
```

You can then add all the config to the `db2` key in either global or `module.config.php`.